# What is the significance or importance of a 7-headed snake?

Tags: vishnu, animals

There are many depictions of Vishnu resting on a Snake. But why is it that the snake is sometimes depicted as 3-headed, 5-headed or 7-headed?

What is the meaning or importance of snakes in Hinduism?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: May be the questions should be separated, right? It is now too broad.

Comment: @a, can you help me with that? :) It would be better I guess :)

Comment: @AAZ: sorry in delay, i didnt see your response. 1. Importance of snake. then 2nd question number of heads of snake. The second one is broad since it will depend on situations and stories.

Comment: No, second one is not a question. It is an example! Only the importance was asked :)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Please be a bit more discriminating in your choice of tags. Nearly every question you have asked so far has been tagged with [belief], and I or another user has had to go through and retag it with something more appropriate.

Answer (score 13):

Snakes are very important in Hinduism. There are many reasons for this; snakes shed their skin, and grow it back later. This represents "rebirth", while also representing death and mortality. Not just that - snakes cannot be tamed; hence, they represent freedom. Another reason is given [here](http://www.khandro.net/mysterious_naga.htm):

> All nagas are considered the offspring of the Rishi or sage, Kasyapa, the son of Marichi.  Kashyapa is said to have had by his twelve wives, other diverse progeny including reptiles, birds, and all sorts of living beings. They are denizens of the netherworld city called Bhogavati.  It is believed that ant-hills mark its entrance.

Also, the same source tells:

> The Indian mahasiddha, Nagarjuna, received his illuminating insights and tantric empowerment with the help of the nagas in the lake beside which he meditated.

From [here](http://hubpages.com/hub/myths-of-naga-in-hinduism),

> According to the Hindu Scriptures, Naga live in the Netherworld called Naga-Loka or Patala-Loka with unimaginable richness. When the Naga were over populated on the earth, Brahma, the Creator, banished them to the underworld. Naga are the children of Kashyap Rishi who married Brahma 13 daughters. Their mother’s name is Kudra. Kashyap is also the father of gods, demons and animals.
>
> Snakes are Lord Shiva’s garland, anklets and armlets. Hindu gods like Bhairav and Mahakala are protected and decorated by snakes. Thousand-headed Naga called Ananta protects Goddess Kali. Like Lord Vishnu, many gods rest on Naga or are protected by Naga. Naga guard Hindu temples and shrines. Naga are depicted on the doors, windows and the walls of the temples. Naga are also the seat of the deity.
>
> Tantra and Yoga, which are the esoteric practices in Hinduism, philosophize about serpent power inside human body. This serpent called Kundalini, depicted as a coiled snake, would be evoked by mysterious yogic practices or tantric rituals. When this serpent power is awakened ignoramus humans are said to be liberated from worldly vices. Literal meaning of Kundalini is coiled Naga.

The multiple heads on the snake is symbolic; it is used to denote protection. This number may vary, for the reason I mention below. As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_worship#Hindu_mythology) says,

> Shesha (Adisesha, Sheshnaga, or the 1000 headed snake) upholds the world on his many heads and is said to be used by Lord Vishnu to rest.

Why does the snake have multiple heads? The Puranas tell that Shesha holds all the planets of the Universe (we now know it is in the solar system) on his hoods. A possibly non-spiritual explanation for the number of heads is said [here](http://www.freebsd.nfo.sk/hinduism/nagovia.htm):

> The seven-headed Naga serpents depicted as statues on Cambodian temples such as Angkor Wat possibly represent the seven races within the Naga society.

Comment: All nagas aren't devtas, only few and it's really difficult to know. I got to know from sewak at Sri Bhairav Dada temple, many times Godly snake give darshan who goes away without hurting any devotee, but at times he had to kill deadly snakes who proved fatal.

Answer (score 3):

Snakes are a symbol of alertness. They signify the raising of awareness as a result of meditation. I assume the number used (3, 5 or 7) is just an artistic rendition.

> If you look at the mythological pictures, you will find Mahavir
>   sitting with a five headed cobra behind him. Or Lord Vishnu is sitting
>   in meditation and there is a cobra behind him. Even in the pictures of
>   Rishis, you will find a cobra with its hood open at the back. Have you
>   seen such pictures? It is a very subtle thing!
>
> See, when you are sitting in meditation, what is happening? Your
>   consciousness is getting alert, opened and awakened, as though in your
>   back ground there is a thousand headed cobra. Cobra signifies
>   alertness.
>
> How many of you feel a lot of alertness in the back of your head
>   during meditation? A sort of wakefulness!
>
> So the cobra is a symbol of the energy that raises and opens up;
>   energy which is alert and at the same time restfulness.
>
> It is not that there was really a cobra at the back of their head, it
>   is a symbol of wakefulness in the deep state of rest, and that is
>   meditation – totally restful, wanting nothing, doing nothing, being
>   nothing and being open, like the hood of a cobra; alert without any
>   effort.
>
> There are two types of descriptions for this. In one they talk about a
>   Cobra, and in another they talk about a flower; it is like a
>   thousand-petaled lotus, blossoming on the top of the head; on the
>   crown chakra.
>
> So some describe it as a flower, very delicate, and some describe it
>   as a cobra which means alert. Both fit very well.

From a talk by Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: http://celebrating-silence-of-life.blogspot.in/2012/11/symbolism-of-five-headed-cobra.html