# Why do many Gods and Goddesses bear a serpent?

Tags: gods, goddess, animals, devi, symbolism

I've observed that many Gods in one form or the other bear a serpent. For example, Devi Durga holds a serpent in one hand. Is there a spiritual significance to this?

Comment: Yes but is there any special significance of snake in Hindu religion?

Comment: I've edited the question mate

Comment: Hope this will answer your query: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/330/11875

Comment: I'm still not satisfied

Comment: Simple snake represents kundalini energy All  are gods because they have their kundalini sakthi awakened reached sashrara so  they go to eternal bliss whenever they want they are not like humans But for Durga she is abhimani devta for the tamas sakhti may be she holds the sexual energy in hand

Comment: @Eyyboss You should consider updating your question stating why you aren't satisfied with the answers in that question by including specific citations. That will make the question more specific and will help potential answerers answer your question.